# How to design SQL lookup table

Tags: t-sql, architecture, relational-database, ssms, entity-relationship

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase the title, which is why I'm struggling to google the solution.

It has been a few years since I did SQL modeling and design and am recently dipping my feet again.

**My issue is this:**

I have a single list of unique ProjectIDs.

Some project's have "walls" against others, meaning a person from one cannot know anything about the other.  I want to implement this logic in a report by hiding columns if the person is a member of a project with one of these "WallFlags" against it.

Validating which projects the person is a member of has been resolved.

The relationship is a zero or many,

**What I want:**

I want a permanent, scalable way to store this information.
I was planning to build a table which stores the project id's, but I can't conceptualize how I would record a situation where a project has a wall against multiple other projects...

Also if anybody knows of resources which help with design that would be very appreciated so I can kick myself into gear

Comment: My first SWAG would be that you need tables for `Projects`, `People`, `PeopleProjects` to assign people to zero or more projects and `ProjectWalls` to identify pairs of projects that are separated by virtual moats. I'd probably go ahead and add triggers to ensure that you can't assign a single person to two projects that are, however distantly, blocked from each other, and to handle changes to project walls that might split a person. TVFs can be written to return, for example, all of the projects `PersonId` is not prohibited from viewing.

Answer (score 0):

What would you do if a person was a member of two project that each had walls against each other?

```
Walls:  ProjIDbase, ProjIDblocked
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the legal department of our company ensures that this will not happen.  And I like the idea of a walls table.  The PK could be random and i'd put in an established date as well. Perhaps an active flag.  I would like to avoid adding in ten rows per project now with the flag, but I see no way around it

Comment: Why not just use those two column as the PK?

Comment: You think another needless column is simpler or more accurate?   That is the natural key and you should use it.   The table has a natural composite key and you think ignore that is going to make things better?

Comment: That took a hostile tone change.  Yes I do think that joining on a surrogate key is simpler than joining on a composite key.  In any case I appreciate your input on this matter, if you know of performance related cons I would love to hear them.  I am relatively new and while natural keys are nice, I find that uniform surrogate keys are easier for someone after me to identify and quickly begin working with (with the right design)

Comment: But it in NOT the right design.   What part of the natural key is composite is not clear.  You think 3NF is merely a performance thing?   Go do what is easy for you.  Why ask a question if you are going to do what is easy for you?  You like PK as "CharCharIntIntIntIntInt" - do you have any idea how naive that is?